# Update mui data-grid with socket only one element added

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

i got a problem while working with mui data-grid and socket.io.
I load initial data from an api which works fine.
But when I want to update the table with data from an websocket is only one element added and overwritten on every change. The code is the following:

Table:

```js
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(props.tableData);

useEffect(() => {
    setTableData(props.tableData);
  }, [props.tableData]);

return (<div key="tradingTableGrid" style={{ height: 450, width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid
            key={"TradingTable"}
            rows={Object.values(tableData)}
            columns={tableHead}
            rowHeight={30}
            pageSize={10}
            onRowClick={(row) => openModal(row)}
          />
</div>);
```

The component where the initial data are loaded and the websocket update is called is the following (i have only added the essential code):

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState(false);
const [socketActive, setSocketActive] = useState(false);

// initial data loading from api
const handleResponse = (response) => {
  var result = {};
  response.forEach((prop) => {
    result = {
      ...result,
      [prop.order_id]: {
        id: prop.order_id,
        orderId: prop.order_id,
        price: prop.price.toString(),
        volume: prop.max_amount_currency_to_trade,
        minVolume: prop.min_amount_currency_to_trade,
        buyVolume: prop.max_volume_currency_to_pay + " €",
        minBuyVolume: prop.min_volume_currency_to_pay + " €",
        user: prop.trading_partner_information.username,
      },
    };
  });
  setData(result);
};

// add from websocket
const addOrder = (order) => {
  if (
    order.trading_pair === "btceur" &&
    order.order_type === "buy" &&
    (order.payment_option === "1" || order.payment_option === "3")
  ) {
    if (typeof data[order.order_id] === "undefined") {
      console.log(data);
      setData({
        ...data,
        [order.order_id]: {
          id: order.order_id,
          orderId: order.order_id,
          price: order.price.toString(),
          volume: order.amount,
          minVolume: order.min_amount,
          buyVolume: Number(order.volume).toFixed(2) + " €",
          minBuyVolume: Number(order.min_amount * order.price).toFixed(2) + " €",
          user: "not set through socket",
        },
      });
    }
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = () => {
    setLoadData(true);
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_APP_BITCOIN_SERVICE + "/order/book?type=buy")
      .then((response) => handleResponse(response.data.orders))
      .catch((exception) => console.error(exception))
      .finally(() => setLoadData(false));
  };

  if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && socketActive === false) {
    loadData();
  }

  const socket = () => {
    const websocket = io("https://ws-mig.bitcoin.de:443/market", {
      path: "/socket.io/1",
    });
    websocket.on("connect", function () {
      setSocketActive(true);
    });
    websocket.on("remove_order", function (order) {
      removeOrder(order);
    });
    websocket.on("add_order", function (order) {
      addOrder(order);
    });

    websocket.on("disconnect", function () {
      setSocketActive(false);
    });
  };

  if (socketActive === false && Object.keys(data).length !== 0) {
    socket();
  }
}, [data, socketActive]);

return (
  <Table
    tableHeaderColor="info"
    tableHead={tableHead}
    tableData={data}
    type="buy"
  />
);
```

Does anyone has an idea why on the update throught the socket only one element in the data is added and on every next call overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

The reason is that the socket handlers are using the state setters from the first render.

as an example take `addOrder`, you create that function within the context of a specific data value, when you call `setData({...data` it will always use the initial state for data. (to understand why see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and also [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) from facebook's react developer Dan Abramov)

### The Solution

what you can do instead is use the functional update syntax that lets you pass a function to setData:

`setData( data => ({...data,`

this ensures the last stored value is always used.

see the react docs on useState [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Now I need to remove from the new data set, but I got only the old one.